# Get column names

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I need to get all of the column names of a table using VBA or Access SQL and iterate through them for validation, does anyone have a solution to this, I have searched Google to no avail.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This will work

```
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")
Dim fld As DAO.Field
For Each fld In rs1.Fields
    MsgBox (fld.Name)
Next
Set fld = Nothing
```

Comment: I generally never use a counter for collections that have their own data type for the items in the collection. I'd use For Each fld In rs1.Fields, instead (with the variable fld as type DAO.Field).

Comment: I've now edited it to fix an oversight in your edit (you omitted changing the counter variable to a field variable).

Answer (score 11):

```
Dim l As Integer

For l = 0 To CurrentDb.TableDefs("tbl_Name").Fields.Count - 1
  Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs("tbl_Name").Fields(l).name
Next l
```

Comment: This is what Feral had 3 years ago, but changed it to the much better code proposed by David. I don't see why you added it (three years later); even less why it got upvotes.

Comment: This method does not require you to open a Recordset. +1