# How to compare table fields with visual basic

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to use Visual Basic for Applications for adding some specific Tables for two Databases (Access-bases, .mdb). In theory I think (?) it is pretty easy, as I can do ''SQL = "INSERT INTO Table SELECT * FROM otherDatabase.Table'' followed by ''CurrentDb.Execute SQL''. Where Table is the name of the Table. My problem is some special cases:

I can expect they have matching Table-names and Field-names, but it can happen that otherDatabase has more Fields than CurrentDb. So if that happens, my INSERT INTO-query fails. Therefore I need to check for such additional fields in the otherDatabase, and add the missing fields before I do the INSERT-query (or at the very least notify the user).

It can also happen that one of the databases lack a Table the other have, so I must also check and hopefully fix that.

**How can I check for these missing Fields and Table, and then insert the missing ones?** Thanks in advance.

```
Sub tableJoin ()

    Dim otherDatabase As Database

    'begin FilePicker
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Optional: FileDialog properties
    fDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    fDialog.Title = "Choose Database"
    fDialog.InitialFileName = "C:\"
    fDialog.Filters.Clear
    fDialog.Filters.Add "Access-files", "*.mdb"

    If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
       Debug.Print fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If



    Set otherDatabase = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(Dialog.SelectedItems(1))

    SQL = "INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM " + fDialog.SelectedItems(1) + ".Table1"
    CurrentDb.Execute SQL

    SQL = "INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT * FROM " + fDialog.SelectedItems(1) + ".Table2"
    CurrentDb.Execute SQL

    SQL = "INSERT INTO Table3 SELECT * FROM " + fDialog.SelectedItems(1) + ".Table3"
    CurrentDb.Execute SQL

    Dim Response
    Response = MsgBox("You've now moved data from " + fDialog.SelectedItems(1) + " to " + CurrentDb.Name, vbOKOnly, Succsess)
    otherDatabase.Close
    CurrentDb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Find all table names - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555174/how-to-loop-through-all-tables-in-an-ms-access-db
Get the field names - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343922/get-column-names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343922/get-column-names)

Comment: Your narrative says Visual Basic script but tag is VBA. They are not the same things. Do you mean VB or VBScript or VBA? Should correct tag or question.

Comment: @June7 I was not aware that Visual Basic script is it's own thing, sorry if that caused some confusion. To be perfectly clear, I use Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications to write my code.

The links were very helpful, but I am stuck on how to find the missing columns/fields (I see both terms being used?) and add them. Maybe I can put something together with my newfound knowledge from you guys, thanks.